# how to 'offset' a date/time using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an input box with a date (user selected).  I want to use moment.js to offset the date selected by a timezone, for example 'Europe/London'.  So lets' say my date is (2/24/2017), how do I get moment to give me the date as:

current date time is 2/24/2017 4:18:00

So I want it to return 2/25/2017 12:18:00 which would be the current time in London England?

```
var x = moment().tz(dateStart, 'London/Europe').format();
```

but it just keeps giving me the date time now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're also loading the timezone data, e.g. [*moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js*](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) has it included for the period 2010 to 2020.

You should include the format to parse when parsing a string, otherwise the parser is just guessing.

'London/Europe' is not a valid [IANA timezone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), the region comes first, then the city, so:

```js
console.log(moment('2/24/2017','MM/DD/YYYY').tz('Europe/London').format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js"></script>
```

Note that when you parse just a date, the time component will be set to local midnight at the start of the day, i.e. 00:00:00 local, based on the host system timezone setting.

Answer (score 0):

you basically trying to get current time for a particular timezone
you did almost correct but i don't see any need to pass the date as `moment()`constructor will get current datetime for your location, and you are trying wrong timezone string correct would be - 'Europe/London'

```
my current time in India now - 
moment().format('DD MM YYYY HH:MM:SS');
"08 03 2017 11:03:27"

for London time zone
moment().tz('Europe/London').format('DD MM YYYY HH:MM:SS');
"08 03 2017 05:03:34"
```